# How to set up a connection to a MySQL-server within Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: php, connection, mysql, dreamweaver

If you have credentials to login in via SFTP to a server that is running PHP and you can access MySQL with SSH, how do you combine these things within Dreamweaver CS4?

Comment: I'd almost think this would be a question for Stackoverflow?

Comment: Not really about programming, more about using software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by opening the Databases panel (top menu: Window->Databases). You'll need to set up a site. Then you should be able to create a database connection to associate with the site.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is dreamweaver leans towards setting up the database connection from a local file or database...which was a simple job using the database (+)add connection and pointing it to either the file or database. Unfortunately when I tried to go live and my remote host is different than the location of my remote hosted database it becomes really a pain. I can transfer and sync my files to the remote host but get a "testing server not defined error" for some unknown reason. My database definition is correct pointing to mysql2.hostingcompany.com but the connection isn't ever made to the remote database.
if i set it back to the local one complete access to all tables. user name and password are correct for my hostingcompany.com database.
I can't set the remote to point to the database and i can't change the testing server to point to it either without getting a failure. so what is the right way to set up a remote database connection?